# How to redirect to links with braces in it

Tags: html, angular

**I am creating an anchor tag in Angular html file.**

`<a target="_self" *ngIf="item.url" [disabled]="item.disable" [href]="item.url">`

Now *item* contains list of values, but some values contain brackets as well, eg: item = ["Microplastics", "M(16)a"]

So anchor tag is working fine for names like *Microplastics* but its not working for the ones with brackets like *M(16)a*. So please tell me how can I make it work.

Comment: Can you elaborate please ?
Can you show your code, as in so far what you have tried and all ?

Comment: If the text is part of a url, try using encodeURIComponent() to encode these characters. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: @Achintha I tried that but encodeURIComponent() doesn't encode brackets.

Comment: What do you mean by not working. Please provide more details. Are these URLs within your site or outside? Note: Angular uses parenthesis for named router outlets. Not sure if that's the case. https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet#description

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to this author's answer, it seems working fine: [Using parenthesis in parameters](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10280#issuecomment-250888263)